# Do Firebase functions follow the firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My firestore security rule look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /user/{uid}/{document=**} {
      allow read,write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
}
```

When I simulate in Firestore, everything looks fine.

I have firebase function to put/get data

```
await document.set({
    name: jbose12,
      });
      console.log('Entered new data into the document');
}
```

Thing is it creates/push data in firebase even if I provide the wrong uid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security rules only apply to access coming directly from web and mobile clients using the Firebase client SDKs.  They don't not apply to backend code, including code that runs in Cloud Functions using the Firebase Admin SDK or other Cloud SDKs.  Backend code will always bypass all rules.

If you want to observe rules in your backend for per-user access, you will have to write the code in the function to check that.  For HTTP type functions, you will need to make your client app pass an ID token to the function, and use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) before performing the write.

Comment: ohh thanks. i am using firebase functions as rest-server for my web application , in this case i don't think it will work.

Comment: Well, the second link I gave illustrates how to do it from both the client and server ends of it. There are also examples on the internet if you search.